# Centering text within editText Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have a linearlayout with a textview, and edittext. How do I center the text within edittext. It appears to be drawn to the bottom as shown below.I want it to be consistent with the baseline similar to that of the textview to its left.

[image]

The layout code is as below:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_left_rounded_corner"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_right_rounded_corner"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why your textView and edittext height is greater than the parent layout?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake! I made parent height also to 30dp and then used gravity:center for the children which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use android:gravity="center" to have the input be centered

Comment: This worked but like masum's comment, the layout width and height also need to be set correctly for it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just do that

```
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="NAME"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_left_rounded_corner"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/et_name"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_right_rounded_corner"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_left_rounded_corner"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="NAME"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_name"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_right_rounded_corner"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```